# Why I am not getting result of this query ,in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get rows from mysql in rails by following query.I am trying first it on console.But this is not working,please help me.

> > name="vikash"
> >     List=User.find_by_sql["SELECT * from users where name like ?",%#{name}%]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this query

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT * from users where name like '%#{name}%'")
```

Comment: this is prone to sql injection

Answer (score 1):

A small mistake in your query.

Space after `find_by_sql` and name interpolation should be done with double quote.

```
name = "vikash"

list = User.find_by_sql ["SELECT * from users where name like ?", "%#{name}%"]
```

Check below links for details

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql

Hope this will help you...

Do not put variable directly into the conditions string will pass the variable to the database as-is. This means that it will be an unescaped variable directly from a user who may have malicious intent.

You can check in console by `name = "vikash'"` and query with the query shown by @sanju

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT * from users where name like '%#{name}%'")
```

And see the difference how malicious characters are escaped by querying with

```
list = User.find_by_sql ["SELECT * from users where name like ?", "%#{name}%"]
```

For further information visit:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
https://railsguide.wordpress.com/2016/03/02/sanitizing-user-input-while-quering/

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `find_by_sql` to the following:

`User.find_by_sql(["SELECT * from users where name like ?", "%#{name}%"])`

Comment: It is showing wrong number of arguments. ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: You might consider using `array` approach as stated above, as `rails` does sanitize your `sql` and protect you from sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
list= User.find_by_sql("SELECT * from users where name like '%#{name}%'")
```